# The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character - when trying to wrap items in rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The images being displayed here are different sizes - so each set of 3 items should be wrapped in a `<div class="row"></div>` in order to keep things from getting messy. But I keep getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

How can I format this so that it doesn't freak out Razor?

```
<div class="row">

     @foreach (var row in Model.Select((item, index) => new { index, item }))
     {
         if (row.index != 0 && row.index % 3 == 0)
         {
            </div><div class="row">
         }

        <div class="col-sm-4 mix @String.Format(@"category-{0}", row.item.Category.ToString())" data-price="64900" data-date="20130521" data-popularity="3">
            <div class="ec-box">
                <div class="ec-box-header"><a href="#">@row.item.Name</a></div>
                <a href="#"><img src="@row.item.Image.URL" alt=""></a>
                <div class="ec-box-footer">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details")" class="btn btn-ar btn-success btn-sm pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> More info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can conditionally close tags...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you are right. Any ideas for a better approach?

Comment: Either use CSS to split into rows (like `width:33%`) or render rows and content of each row in nested loops. (There are plenty questions on batching of `Select` into groups of n)

Answer (score 0):

You are frustrating the heck out of the parser with this

```
@String.Format(@"category-{0}", row.item.Category.ToString())
```

Why not?

```
@("category-" + row.item.Category.ToString())
```

Notice the use of curly brackets `{0}` in your statement.

Comment: Made the change - but i'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas? For what it's worth, it seems to be mad at the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confusing razor with the way you put the `@foreach` block. Try to change your code to the following

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Select((item, index) => new { index, item }))
{
    if (row.index == 0 || row.index % 3 == 0)
    {
        <div class="row">
    }

    <div class="col-sm-4 mix @String.Format(@"category-{0}", row.item.Category.ToString())" data-price="64900" data-date="20130521" data-popularity="3">
        <div class="ec-box">
            <div class="ec-box-header"><a href="#">@row.item.Name</a></div>
            <a href="#"><img src="@row.item.Image.URL" alt=""></a>
            <div class="ec-box-footer">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details")" class="btn btn-ar btn-success btn-sm pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> More info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    if (row.index % 3 == 2 || row.index == Model.Count - 1)
    {
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the `@` on the if statement.

```
@if (row.index != 0 && row.index % 3 == 0)
```

Comment: Still running into the same error, even with the @.